# MongoDump Failed: error writing data for collection `collection` to disk: error reading collection: EOF

Tags: mongodb, memory, mongodb-3.6, node.js

[BACKUP COMMAND] `mongodump --host 127.0.0.1 -d database --port 27017 --username username --password password --out /output/path/mongodump_DATE_12_00_AM`

[ISSUE] Failed: error writing data for collection `collection1` to disk: **error reading collection: EOF**

MongoDB `v3.6.5`

The Mongo Database and the Node JS application is running in the docker container, Linux Machine. Mongo DB total backup size is 41GB. We are running the backup command on daily basis it is working fine for 10 to 15 days but after that getting above mentioned error intermittently.

[WORKAROUND] = As a workaround, if I stop and start all the NODE application services, application container and MongoDB container then the issue is getting resolved.

For Testing purpose before doing workaround(stop & start container), I ran the mongodump command only for that error collection `mongodump --host 127.0.0.1 -d database --port 27017 --username username --password password --collection collection1 --out /output/path/mongodump_DATE_12_00_AM` then **it is working fine.**

So my questions are:

- Is this application memory leak issue?
- Or, Is System low memory(RAM) issue? Linux server TOTAL RAM SIZE is: `12GB`.

  - If system low memory issue means it should failed on every time but here it failed after a few days.